# Why does the expression 011 == 11 evaluate to false?

Tags: php

When I was practicing in php, I noticed, that the following expressions yield strange results:

```php
011 == 11   // false
'011' == 11 // true
```

Shouldn't they both evaluate to same result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because `011` is treated as an **octal** value because of the leading `0`.

Here's the more in-depth explanation:

1. The `011` literal is recognized as an **octal** value
2. It is then **converted to decimal value**, which equals to `9`
3. The actual comparison happens which looks like the following: `9 == 11 // false`

As of the `'011' == 11`, it evaluates to `true`, because when string is compared to integer, it's coerced to the integer value as well. Interestingly, the leading zero in the string is ignored in the proccess and the php interpreter treats the value as **a decimal rather than an octal one**!

Comment: Very nice explanation.

Comment: I knew about the octal representation when unquoted but assumed the same for quoted, interesting indeed!

Comment: True! `var_dump(011 == 9);` `var_dump(011 === 9);`